# How does whatsapp website start with 'web.'

Tags: web, dns, hosting, registering

How is whatsapp website web.whatsapp.com and not [www.whatsapp.com](http://www.whatsapp.com).
How can we register a website domain starting with 'web.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you own a domain, you can add any subdomains you want to it. It can generally be configured in server settings. If you use a hosting provider, they should have an option to add a subdomain too.

Oh, and the "web" is not exactly a replacement of "www". While "www.example.com" and "example.com" point to the same resource, "subdomain.example.com" will point elsewhere unless you set it to redirect.

Comment: " the "web" is not exactly a replacement of "www". " It could completely be. There is nothing magical with these names, it is all the same for computers, all that matters is their resolution to IP addresses.